# Looking for duplicate transactions within a 5 minutes over a 24 hour time period

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am looking for duplicate transactions between a 5 minute window during a 24 hour period. I am trying to find users abusing other users access. Here is what I have so far, but it is only searching the past 5 minutes and not searching the 24 hour period. It is ORACLE.

```
SELECT p.id, Count(*) count
FROM tranledg tl,
     patron p
WHERE p.id = tl.patronid
  AND tl.trandate > (sysdate-5/1440)
  AND tl.plandesignation in ('1')
  AND p.id in (select id from tranledg tl where tl.trandate > (sysdate-1))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*)> 1
```

Example data:

Patron

```
id  |  Name      
--------------------------
1   | Joe
2   | Henry
3   | Tom
4   | Mary
5   | Sue
6   | Marie
```

Tranledg

```
tranid  |  trandate              |   location    |  patronid     
--------------------------
1       |  2015-03-01 12:01:00   |   1500        |  1
2       |  2015-03-01 12:01:15   |   1500        |  2
3       |  2015-03-01 12:03:30   |   1500        |  1
4       |  2015-03-01 12:04:00   |   1500        |  3
5       |  2015-03-01 15:01:00   |   1500        |  4
6       |  2015-03-01 15:01:15   |   1500        |  4
7       |  2015-03-01 17:01:15   |   1500        |  2
8       |  2015-03-01 18:01:30   |   1500        |  1
9       |  2015-03-01 19:02:00   |   1500        |  3
10      |  2015-03-01 20:01:00   |   1500        |  4
11      |  2015-03-01 21:01:00   |   1500        |  5
```

I would expect the following data to return:

```
ID  |   COUNT
1   |    2
4   |    2
```

Comment: Please, add your table schema and desired result.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: I'm guessing Oracle with `sysdate` in there (MySQL has `SYSDATE()`, but it's a function).

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You are correct. It is oracle

Comment: I think your sample data is wrong. `1` doesnt have two records in 2 minutes span

Comment: Data is correct, its tran 1 and 3 and it should be a 5 minute period.

Comment: Then the title is wrong.

Comment: What to do if there is more than window for `patronid`? And what when the windows are overlapping (e.g. 12:00, 12:05, 12:10)?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Postgres online, Oracle version very similar, only be carefull with date operation.

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/AHEQ41664)**

You need a self join.

```
SELECT T1.patronid, count(*)
FROM Tranledg T1
JOIN Tranledg T2
  ON T2."trandate" BETWEEN T1."trandate" + '-2 minute' AND T1."trandate" + '2 minute'
 AND T1."patronid" = T2."patronid"
 AND T1."tranid" <> T2."tranid"
GROUP BY T1.patronid;
```

**OUTPUT**

You need to fix the data, so 1 has two records.

[image]

Comment: `"trandate" + '-2 minute'` should `trandate - interval '2' minute` if you want standard SQL that also works on Oracle

Comment: Not seeing where you designated it being a 24 hour period.

Comment: I didnt because looks like you know how handle that, Can't you add a `where  T1."trandate"  > sysdate -1`?

Comment: I am receiving an ORA-01722:invalid number with Juan Carlos solution.

Comment: Sorry I dont have an oracle server to test the sample, But the logic is there, just check the right sintaxis. What is your sql level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic clause with a range window like this:

```
select *
  from (select tranid
             , patronid
             , count(*) over(partition by patronid
                             order by trandate
                             range between       0 preceding
                                       and 5/60/24 following) count
          from tranledg
         where trandate >= sysdate-1)
 where count > 1
```

It will output all transactions that are followed with more ones for the same `patronid` in the range of 5 minutes along with the count of the transactions in the range (you did not specify what to do if there are more than one such a range or when the ranges are overlapping).

Output on the test data (without the condition for `sysdate` as it already passed):

```
TRANID PATRONID COUNT
------ -------- -----
     1        1     2
     5        4     2
```

Comment: MIK, that did exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks for your help.